# Is there something like Dictionary.Replace(key,new KeyValuePair<newKey><newValue>) in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I wish to replace a certain entry of Dictionary, at the same index.
I am thinking on the lines of creating an extension method(This would involve:

1. Iterating through all the keys, until that key is found
2. Then adding the new key value pair
3. Append the remaining keys
   )
   Any other optimal way to do this?

Its like if I have
list

```
{a,1}
{b,2}
{c,3}
```

I want it to have

```
{a,1}
{f,5}
{c,3}
By Something like dic.Replace(b,f,5)
```

Comment: I believe Dictionary order isn't guaranteed so there's no real way to do this, no. Not 100% certain on that though. That's why there's no `RemoveAt(int index)` or anything like that.

Comment: Why not simply `dictionary[key] = newValue;`?

Comment: Do you mean _index_ or _key_?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That would add a new value, but not replace the orignal one. Its like if I have
list
{a,1}
{b,2}
{c,3}
I want it to have {a,1}{f,5}{c,3}

Comment: Dictionaries don't have indexes, and if you're iterating through the keys to find its value you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @RonakAgrawal No, that will replace the value for that key with the new value.

Comment: @RonakAgrawal That would *replace* the original value, not append it.

Comment: It looks like what you really want is to add one key-value and remove the other as two separate steps.  The order should not matter.  If order does matter to you then `Dictionary` is not the correct data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the key and add the new one.

```
    public void Replace<T1,T2>(Dictionary<T1, T2> d, T1 key, T1 newKey, T2 newValue)
    {
        if (d.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            d.Remove(key);
            d.Add(newKey, newValue);
        }
    }
```

There is no built-in Replace method. but you can use this method. Example:

```
Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>();    
d.Add("a", 1);
Replace(d, "a", "b", 2);
// will change the key "a" with value 1 to key "b" with value 2
```

Answer (score 5):

The order in a Dictionary is not preserved, so what you are trying to do is not possible.

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

Here is the [documentation in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

There is however a [`OrderedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) and a [`SortedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You have to investgate if either one would be suitable for your needs

Comment: one thing, if i add elements in a certain order to dictionary, and if iterate through all keys, the keys appear in the order they were added. I just want to preserve this order.

Comment: @RonakAgrawal The order is just an implementation detail.  The next version might change it and break your code (though it's unlikely).

Comment: That is just by chance, an implementation detail. You can't rely on that because it might change at any given point in time. The `Dictionary` is the wrong data structure for what you are trying to do if you want to impose an order.

Comment: @RonakAgrawal And based on how that implementation detail works you'd have to create a new `Dictionary` or remove everything after the insert point and reinsert in order to do what you want, so it's definitely the wrong data structure for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no .Replace() method for dictionaries by default. Dictionaries are unindexed data structures, so there is no point in iterating through all the keys - you can simply add the new data and then remove the old one, like this:

```
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(newKey))
        {
            dictionary.Remove(newKey);
        }
        dictionary.Add(newKey, newValue);
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(oldKey))
        {
            dictionary.Remove(oldKey);
        }
```

Comment: This will [throw an exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx) if the key already exists.

Comment: True! Edited my little piece.

Comment: The `Add` will throw, not the `Remove`.  You could just do `dictionary[newKey] = newValue;`  That will replace the value if the key is present or add if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

A `Dictionary` does not have indices, only keys. You are probably looking for `OrderedDictionary` or a custom combination of `List` and `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *effective* **guaranteed** way to do that. But let assume you really want what you said. Well, although definitely not a good practice, the way `Dictinary<Tkey, TValue>` is implemented currently actually allows that behavior. If you remove a key and immediately add a new item, it will appear at the same position as the removed when enumerating. That's why the following is working:

```
public static bool Replace<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> target, TKey key, TKey newKey, TValue newValue)
{
    if (target.ContainsKey(newKey) ? !target.Comparer.Equals(key, newKey) : !target.Remove(key)) return false;
    target[newKey] = newValue;
    return true;
}
```

So, does it work currently - yes (fact). Is it guaranteed to work in the future - no. Should one use such techniques - well, it's up to him.

Answer (score -1):

I misunderstood the question.

In this case, something like this should work:

```
private bool ChangeKey(string oldKey, string newKey, string value) {
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(oldKey))
    {
        dictionary.Remove(oldKey);
        dictionary.Add(newKey, value);
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: According to Servy's comments, you don't need to check if the key exists first. Either it's there and it assigns the value or not. So your pre-edit answer was equally valid.

Comment: no what if op wants to change the key too. because thats what i understand from question. you are currently just changing the value.( i did not downvote)

Comment: I do no think that is what the OP wanted.

Comment: I've changed the code. Something like this should work.

Comment: It's still an evil thing you are doing.. plz check Frank J's answer